# Writing to register on I2C device, returns device busy

Tags: i2c, raspberry-pi

I am trying to write data to a register on an I2C chip from the Raspberry Pi, when I use i2cdetect I get UU, which I understand is an error.

```
sudo i2cdetect -y 1

   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f

00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- UU 
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

When I try to use SMbus python module to write to the desired register I get the following error:

```
bus.write_byte_data(DEVICE_ADDRESS, CONTROL_REG, CON_VAL)
IOError: [Errno 16] Device or resource busy
```

Are there any usual reasons for this or things to try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This typically means that you have already loaded a driver which is accessing this device.

Unload the driver using e.g. rmmod and you should be good to go.

Just to mention it: You can also use i2cset and i2cget to set and get values directly instead of altering via Python.

Comment: Thanks that did the trick (used modprobe -r), i2cdetect and smbus now work. I would like to try write to the register when the module is started in a bash script here: modprobe i2c-dev
modprobe i2c:mcp7941x
echo mcp7941x 0x6f > /sys/class/i2c-dev/i2c-$i/device/new_device              any ideas how to?

Comment: would i2cset be the correct thing to use?

Comment: That's probably the easiest thing to do, yes. Yet, you need to call i2cset BEFORE you load the module. Once the module is loaded, only the module may access the device. I don't know if it fits your design, but you could also modify the driver to perform that access during the driver init.

Comment: thanks for this clue, but still not quite getting it.  what is the module you guys are referring to exactly?  i.e. you say "unload the driver using rmmod <module here>" or "used mmodprobe -r <module here>".  which driver or module?

Comment: The module is "probably" named mcp7941x, there should be an appropriate driver for it named something like mcp7941x.ko in your file system at /etc/modules. Yet, this is just a guess. i2cdetect doesn't actually tell you which device uses a specific address, just that one does.

Answer (score 0):

Though it is very late to answer this, recently I had similar issue with my 9$ chip's i2c module axp209 (power management IC).

By default i2-tools/py-smbus module does not provide an option to forcefully open a i2c-device-address( for safe reasons). But i2get command gives option '-y' to read/write.

So i forked i2c-tools/py-smbus in [github](https://github.com/GssMahadevan/i2c-tools) to allow python code also to have similar option. I have changed 3 lines in python module code.

One can see example of my modified python module code at [py-smbus github](https://github.com/GssMahadevan/chip_axp209_tool).

This modified py-smbus modules can be used for raspberry also